# How to design erd where employee is a customer too?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, erd

I have a scenario of a movie theatre and in this scenario an employee can be a customer too (because they can buy tickets).

I created two entities, `customer` and `employee`. If I make `emp_id` of `employee` a foreign key in `customer` then it makes an employee a customer too:

Customer: cust_id, Name, age, emp_id
Employee: emp_id, Name, age

But when I do this, data of `employee` gets repeated in `customer`. What should I do??

Comment: One possible way: Have a person table for all persons (I do believe none of your customers are companies?). And then in the customer table just reference to the person table. Likewise in the employee table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing when I look at your tables, you shouldn't really store `age`. Store birthdate or birth year, so that you won't have to update it every year, because age is relative to current year.

Please read on, or skip to **TL;DR** part if you want my opinion about this.

For the issue you are having there can be multiple design choices and I find it primarily opinion based on which one to choose from.

**One option** would be to create one table for storing person-related data and include type of the person in this table, so that you will either have customers or employees. This way, your employee can also be treated as a customer, but you know that it's a *special one*. This way you can convert record of an employee to a customer when he/she is no longer an employee.

**Another way to approach this** is to treat them as you already have it and deal with the fact that you are repeating data. Unless you have a large amount of employees (this should not be the case for movie theatre) this is a valid approach as well, since obviously they can be customers, but I assume you would like to discount them or for some reason distinguish between those two types of clients.

**Like to keep it the way it currently is**, but don't want to repeat the data in order not to make mistakes? Alter columns which are shared for both tables and make them nullable. Use trigger or some other rule mechanism to check if `emp_id` is filled and then keep all other common column values `null`. This way though you will need to take care of pulling the data from additional table, so a `LEFT JOIN` is required here to pull the data about customers which are also employees.

**And there are much more to choose from** ...

**TL;DR**

If you ask me, I'd most likely go with **first option** to store person-related data within one table and either create a type of person or have different tables for employees and customers which will be in 1:1 relation with person table.

That said, it could look like:

- Person (person_id, name, birth_year)
- Employee (person_id, ...) *(store only employee related data here)*
- Customer (person_id, ...) *(store only customer related data here)*

As a side note, it might be a good idea to figure out how do you want to differentiate people in general. You have not presented scope for the entire system, so it's hard to give some advices around that.

Comment: Okay your suggestions are considered....but if a employee gets ticket of a movie show then he becomes a customer too. So if i create another entity tickets ...and make emp id and cust id a fk in ticket...does it make both a customer.. does that way count?

Comment: In tickets sold you would only create FK to cust_id. Employees don't buy tickets, they are customers. And you would need a record in Customer with the same person_id that you have for an Employee.

Answer (score 0):

If there is only two roles of customer and employee, you can use one table to store the users, like this:

```
person(id, name, birth, is_customer, is_employee, ...)
```

But if you consider more extension in the future, you can add a role table, like this:

```
role(id, name, ...)
person(id, name, birth, roles, ...)
```

the column `roles` can store with json data like `[1,2]` or string like `1,2`, it depends what you like and mysql version.